# How to pass multiple build-args variable to dockerfile

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using a bitbucket-pipelines for my dotnet project. My project consist Dockerfile in the root directory and I want to pass multiple variable to that dockerfile but I am getting an error:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

Here is my step below:

```
- step:
        name: Build Image
        services:
          - docker
        script:
        - docker build \
          --build-arg VARIABLE_ONE=1 \
          --build-arg VARIABLE_TWO=2 \
          --build-arg VARIABLE_THREE=3 \
          --build-argVARIABLE_FOUR=4 \
          -t "$IMAGE_NAME" .
```

I tried the command locally on my bash terminal and its working but not working on pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the slashes.

```
    - docker build
      --build-arg VARIABLE_ONE=1
      --build-arg VARIABLE_TWO=2
      --build-arg VARIABLE_THREE=3
      --build-argVARIABLE_FOUR=4
      -t "$IMAGE_NAME" .
```

Research YAML format and its string escaping rules `>` `|`. Check YAML to JSON converters to see what is the resulting string.